# Which one to duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am tempted to vote to re-open this question:

[What are the professional standards for FBI agents?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26991/what-are-the-professional-standards-for-fbi-agents)

Currently it is closed as a duplicate of this question:

[Are American FBI agents not allowed to have personal opinions?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26909/are-american-fbi-agents-not-allowed-to-have-personal-opinions)

My reasoning is simple, the one currently marked duplicate right now stands at +2, the non-duplicate stands at 0 with *4 close votes*. The one currently closed has an accepted answer, the one almost closed has a good answer but not yet accepted. I think the first one posted (the one almost closed) is a bit more hostile to opposing views at the outset, because who would argue someone is not allowed to have an opinion? Whereas the second one posted is much more factual in nature.

If my finger twitches unexpectedly I may cast the deciding vote for closing the older question, leaving the one that is arguably better (as in brings a bit less baggage to the table as questions go) marked as a duplicate of a question that was deemed not a good fit for this site.

Would it be appropriate to re-open the new one and close the older one as a duplicate of the newer question (or close it for another reason)?

Comment: Related at [meta.se]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183780/