# Was this duplicate closure correct?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

My question

[What are the professional standards for FBI agents?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26991/what-are-the-professional-standards-for-fbi-agents)

was closed as a "duplicate" of

[Are American FBI agents not allowed to have personal opinions?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26909/are-american-fbi-agents-not-allowed-to-have-personal-opinions)

Worth noting that the questions are likely to get, and did get, different answers. My question was asking about a document of what they can do and what they can't. The other one, while certainly related, was asking whether or not they are allowed to have personal opinions -- ultimately a narrower question, and not likely to elicit the answer mine got.

Comment: I was also curious about this, and asked [this meta question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/which-one-to-duplicate) regarding the second questions' closure. I was more interested though in reversing which one was considered the "duplicate."

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't the one who marked it as a duplicate, but both questions have the same essence.  They're about whether or not Trump's concerns about the Mueller probe are justified.  The duplicate designation makes total sense to me.